# Representing element as boolean with JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

We have this XML:

```
  <Summary>
     <ValueA>xxx</ValueA>
     <ValueB/>
  </Summary>
```

`<ValueB/>` will never have any attributes or inner elements.  It's a boolean type element - it exists (true) or it doesn't (false).

JAXB generated a Summary class with a String valueA member, which is good.  But for ValueB, JAXB generated a ValueB inner class and a corresponding member:

```
@XmlElement(name = "ValueB")
protected Summary.ValueB valueB;
```

But what I'd like is a `boolean` member and *no* inner class:

```
@XmlElement(name = "ValueB")
protected boolean valueB;
```

How can you do this?

I'm not looking to regenerate the classes, I'd like to just make the code change manually.

---

**Update**: In line with the accepted answer, we created a new method returning the boolean value conditional on whether valueB == null.

As we are using Hibernate, we annotated valueB with `@Transient` and annotated the boolean getter with Hibernate's `@Column` annotation.

Comment: Do you really need a boolean field? Why not just boolean getter/setter methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite logic jaxb creates an inner class as it thinks that  is a commplexAttribute

Instead of changing it to a boolean you could also check `null == valueB` if you put

`@XmlElement(name = "ValueB", nillable='true')
protected Summary.ValueB valueB;`

in your logic.

or add an extra getter that does not have @XMl.... and returns computed state of valueB
perhaps what you want is possible with JAXB I have not needed it before.

Comment: Yup, that would work.  Would prefer to not have the inner class..  would be simpler.

Answer (score 7):

Use an XmlAdaptor:

```
package com.example.xml.adaptor;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class BooleanToEmptyObjectAdapter extends XmlAdapter<EmptyObject, Boolean> {
    @Override
    public EmptyObject marshal(final Boolean v) {
        return v != null && v ? new EmptyObject() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(final EmptyObject v) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And a dummy object for it to serialize:

```
package com.example.xml.adaptor;

public class EmptyObject {
    // EMPTY
}
```

Then in your object, use a `Boolean` (not a `boolean`) field:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FooElement")
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement()
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanToEmptyObjectAdapter.class)
    private final Boolean isPresent = false;

    ...
    // You might need to @XmlTransient your getter/setter, or JAXB might complain about redefinition
    @XmlTransient
    public boolean isPresent() {
        return this.isPresent;
    }
}
```

This should produce `<isPresent/>` element when true, but omit it when false.

Comment: Annotate @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) on the class then the @XmlTransient is not needed, only the explicitly annotated properties will be considered.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the getter and setters should have the Boolean object as the return type (for the getter) and the parameter type (for the setter)... using the primitive type on either or both didn't work for me.